# Где в Android Studio брать встроенные векторные изображения .xml

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, vector-drawable

В одном из проектов увидел .xml изображение с кодом:

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    android:viewportHeight="24" android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="@android:color/white" android:pathData="M21.6,18.2L13,11.75v-0.91c1.65,-0.49 2.8,-2.17 2.43,-4.05c-0.26,-1.31 -1.3,-2.4 -2.61,-2.7C10.54,3.57 8.5,5.3 8.5,7.5h2C10.5,6.67 11.17,6 12,6s1.5,0.67 1.5,1.5c0,0.84 -0.69,1.52 -1.53,1.5C11.43,8.99 11,9.45 11,9.99v1.76L2.4,18.2C1.63,18.78 2.04,20 3,20h9h9C21.96,20 22.37,18.78 21.6,18.2zM6,18l6,-4.5l6,4.5H6z"/>
</vector>
```

Однако так и не нашёл, откуда подобные изображения беруться, если использовать drawable -> New -> Vector Asset - там находятся совершенно другие изображения (которые, как я понял, используются для иконок)
Больше ничего по этой теме я не нашёл

Comment: Ручками пишутся по документации подобные ресурсы.

Comment: Возможно это так же через Vector Asset сконвертировали svg и руками поменяли цвета, заливку.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо обычных встроенных иконок вы можете использовать эти например https://materialdesignicons.com Чтобы установить их как xml нажимаете на иконку>Icon Package>.XML Vector Drawable. И перемещаете файл в ваш проект.

Answer (score 0):

Вот [сайт](https://www.flaticon.com) с черно-белыми и цветными векторными картинками